# Java XML with namespace issue

Tags: java, xml

I have this code:

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = docBuilder.parse(representation.getStream());
                Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
                NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName("xnat:MRSession.scan.file");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        // do something with the current element
```

my problem is with `getElementsByTagName("xnat:MRSession.scan.file")`

my xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xnat:MRSession "REMOVED DATA IGNORE">
<xnat:sharing>
<xnat:share label="23_MR1" project="BOGUS_GSU">
<!--hidden_fields[xnat_experimentData_share_id="1",sharing_share_xnat_experimentDa_id="xnat_E00001"]-->
</xnat:share>
</xnat:sharing>
<xnat:fields>
<xnat:field name="studyComments">
<!--hidden_fields[xnat_experimentData_field_id="1",fields_field_xnat_experimentDat_id="xnat_E00001"]-->S</xnat:field>
</xnat:fields>
<xnat:subject_ID>xnat_S00002</xnat:subject_ID>
<xnat:scanner manufacturer="GE MEDICAL SYSTEMS" model="GENESIS_SIGNA"/>
<xnat:prearchivePath>/home/ryan/xnat_data/prearchive/BOGUS_OUA/20120717_131900137/23_MR1</xnat:prearchivePath>
<xnat:scans>
<xnat:scan ID="1" UID="1.2.840.113654.2.45.2.108830" type="SAG LOCALIZER" xsi:type="xnat:mrScanData">
<!--hidden_fields[xnat_imageScanData_id="1"]-->
<xnat:image_session_ID>xnat_E00001</xnat:image_session_ID>
<xnat:quality>usable</xnat:quality>
<xnat:series_description>SAG LOCALIZER</xnat:series_description>
<xnat:scanner manufacturer="GE MEDICAL SYSTEMS" model="GENESIS_SIGNA"/>
<xnat:frames>29</xnat:frames>
<xnat:file URI="/home/ryan/xnat_data/archive/BOGUS_OUA/arc001/23_MR1/SCANS/1/DICOM/scan_1_catalog.xml" content="RAW" file_count="29" file_size="3968052" format="DICOM" label="DICOM" xsi:type="xnat:resourceCatalog">
```

So Basically I need to be able to iterate through all the xnat:MRSession/xnat:scan/xnat:file
elements and make some changes. Problem is

```
getElementsByTagName("xnat:MRSession.scan.file")
```

Is always null. Please help. Thanks

Comment: What in the documentation makes you think it should work the way you're using it?

Comment: The documentation is unclear to me. I just need to know what the proper syntax is to specific the xnat:file element. Any light you can shine on this would be very helpful. Obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: It seems to me that what you need is xPath, not `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: xpath huh? Any example you can point me to?

Comment: @user1332868 Google and the javadocs should get you started there. That said, I'd use an alternate DOM like JDOM in this case, the W3C API is fairly awkward when it comes to XPath.

Comment: andrea thanks I'll get started there

Comment: ok so this is what I cam up with: `Representation representation = representItem(exp.getItem(),MediaType.TEXT_XML);
    
   Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(representation.getStream());
   XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("/xnat:MRSession/xnat:scan/xnat:file");
   `                  This give me an InvocationTaretException   This looks like it should work

Comment: the error occurs when SAXBuilder is instantiated

Comment: Here is an example using the `javax.xml.xpath` APIs in the JDK/JRE with namespaces:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644994/parse-xml-with-namespaces-in-java-using-xpath/11647407#11647407

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following using XPath:

```
Document document = // the parsed document
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
NodeList allFileNodes = xPathFactory.newXPath().evaluate("\\XNAT_NAMESPACE:file", document.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Instead XNAT_NAMESPACE you would need to specify the exact namespace that is meant with the prefix "xnat" in your example.