# How to extract data from <dc> tag in java?

Tags: java, epub

I am currently trying to extract the tag element `< dc:title >` from an epub in Java. However, i tried using

```
doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("dc:title"));
```

and it only showed `2nd element :com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl`. I would like to know how can I extract `< dc:tittle >` ?

**Here is my code:**

```
File fXmlFile = new File("file directory");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

System.out.println("1st element :" +  doc.getElementsByTagName("dc");
System.out.println("2nd element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("dc:title"));
```

**System output:**

```
1st element : com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@4f53e9be
2nd element :com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@e16e1a2
```

**Added Sample Data**

```
<dc:title>
  <![CDATA[someData]]>
</dc:title>
<dc:creator>
  <![CDATA[someData]>
</dc:creator>
<dc:language>someData</dc:language>
```

Comment: The `dc:` part is a namespace prefix. You should parse the XML document with namespace awareness. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644994/parse-xml-with-namespaces-in-java-using-xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getElementsByTagName(String)` is return a List of matching elements (note plural 's'). You then need to specify which element (such as by using `.item(index)` to access a Node instance) you want to use. Therewith, you can using `getNodeValue()` on that `Node` object.

EDITED: because of the CDATA element, rather use `Node.getTextContent()`:

```
NodeList elems = doc.getElementsByTagName("dc:title");
Node item = elems.item(0);
System.out.println(item.getTextContent());
```

Comment: I did test your method but it still doesn't work. For index(0) = NULL , index(1) = java.lang.NullPointerException . I have added some sample data that i wanted to display at my post.

Comment: Your selectors are looking wrong. "dc" is the namespace prefix and not the tagname. Does it work using: `doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "title");` [Namespaced tagnames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagNameNS%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) ?
Also your example is looking not well formed - you should add a common root element.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion. Still return the same result like `2nd element :com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@7e0d8db1` The example is just a partial code. It has root element, and the root element is something like this `<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"  version="3.0"> <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> <dc:title>
  <![CDATA[someData]]>
</dc:title>`

Comment: But are you now able to call `.item(0).getNodeValue()` on the return NodeList object?

Comment: @Drew - ok, i forgot the CDATA. I edited my Answer, maybe this helps

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using xpath to get the desired output.
Also, refer following link for examples.
https://www.journaldev.com/1194/java-xpath-example-tutorial
For example:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//dc:title/text()";
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println(nodes.item(0).getNodeValue());
```